# run cmd batch file using start-process

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-4.0

I am trying to run a CMD file using a start-process in powershell and still receiving an error:

```
'Changes847.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I would like to seek some assistance/guidance.  Here's my code.

```
$ScriptPath     = 'C:\Codes\Db\Changes1.cmd'
$DatabaseServer = 'TestMachine'
$DatabaseName   = 'TestDB'
$ExecuteSQL     = "$($ScriptPath) $($DatabaseServer) $($DatabaseName)"


$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "\c " + $ExecuteSQL
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```

Comment: What powershell version are you using? Your tags aren't very clear about it...

Comment: Are you trying to run `Changes847.cmd` or `Changes1.cmd`? Your error message doesn't match the code you're running. Anyway, replace all of your code with `& 'C:\Codes\Db\Changes1.cmd' 'TestMachine' 'TestDB'`.

Comment: Changes1.cmd, I copied the wrong error.

Comment: 'm using powershell v4.0

Comment: Your argument, i.e the `cmd.exe` option should be a forward slash, not a backward slash, e.g. **`"/c "`**. I'm unsure about your `$ExecuteSQL` are the first three variables just to show us what the received parameters were, or is that genuinely what your script looks like?

Comment: @Link If you copied the wrong error then please update your question with the error you're actually getting. Also, did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

So multiple issues. One is your $ExecuteSQL variable as you have no spaces etc so it is formatted wrong. Next issues is as @Ansgar Wiechers stated with the \c instead of /c. I just created a dummy cmd script to write parameters to file like so for testing.

```
@echo on
echo %~1 >> C:\temp\testcmd.txt
echo %~2 >> C:\temp\testcmd.txt
```

Here is edited powershell script below.

```
$ScriptPath = 'C:\temp\test.cmd'
$DatabaseServer = 'TestMachine'
$DatabaseName = 'TestDB'
$ExecuteSQL = $($ScriptPath) + " " + $($DatabaseServer) + " " + $($DatabaseName)

$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "/c " + $ExecuteSQL
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```

Please notice those two changes above I made. I also have different file paths so I could test on my side. This works fine on my workstation and should resolve your issue.